# App Promo Code Expiration

Tags: promotion-code

The Apple promo code expires in 4 weeks, but what exactly expires? Using the the promo code to download an app, or running the app itself?

If somebody receives a promo code, but they decide to download the app two month later. Would they be able to download it?

If somebody uses a promo code immediately to download an app, does the app expire after 4 weeks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once an application has been redeemed with a promotional code, it is "owned" by the redeemer - it does not expire.

The code itself will expire after 28 days and will not be redeemable. (But anyone who already redeemed it will still have the application).

Comment: I assume this applies to In-App purchase promo codes too. Can someone confirm this?